# How to create an array of student names in XCODE

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
NSArray *student = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"peter", @"Daniel", @"Mary", @"Yanah", @"Raju", @"Sue" count:<#(NSUInteger)#>]
```

What do I write after "Sue"?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking.  What's wrong with what you wrote?  What do you want to happen?

Comment: Why don't you use literals like: `@[ @"peter", @"Daniel", @"Mary", @"Yanah", @"Raju", @"Sue" ]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *student = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"peter", @"Daniel", @"Mary", @"Yanah", @"Raju", @"Sue", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

The API you are using is inappropriate because `objects` must be a C array for example

```
NSString *names[3];
names[0] = @"peter";
names[1] = @"Daniel";
names[2] = @"Mary";

NSArray *students = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: names count:3];
```

In your case it's highly recommended to use the modern literal syntax:

```
NSArray *students = @[@"peter", @"Daniel", @"Mary", @"Yanah", @"Raju", @"Sue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it in following ways

STEP 1:

```
NSArray *student = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"peter", @"Daniel", @"Mary", @"Yanah", @"Raju", @"Sue", nil];
```

STEP 2:

```
NSArray *student = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"peter", @"Daniel", @"Mary", @"Yanah", @"Raju", @"Sue", nil];
```

STEP 3:

```
NSArray *student = @[@"peter", @"Daniel", @"Mary", @"Yanah", @"Raju", @"Sue"];
```